# Increment variable within python regex sub

Tags: python, excel

I have a code, where I would like to increment a variable inside a while loop used in python regex sub.

I know the variable increments, because I use it to save the filename as (sw_file_1, sw_file_2, sw_file_3, ...).

The code is to replace numbers within selected excel sheet range. but only the number in the first worksheet is replaced (which is not what I want).

i.e if I start the variable at 1, all the files have 1 as the replacement number, but I want; 2 as replacement, in file 2.xlsx, 3  in file 3.xlsx.

The code is below:

````
i = 1

while i < 5:
    a = i
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=18, min_col=2, max_col=91, max_row=41):
        for cell in row:
            

    # get the formula from the cell 
            cv = cell.value

    # apply regex sub to formula, to replace number
            formula_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d(?=\*)') 
            formula = formula_regex.sub( f"{a}", cv) 

    # write formula to cell
            cell.value = formula
            
        filename = 'sw_file_' + str(a) + '.xlsx'


    wb.save(filename)
    i += 1
     ```
````

Comment: It doesn't look like you are changing what worksheet you are looking at. In your loop you're always acting on rows from `ws` do you need to get the right worksheet before you start the first `for ...` loop?

Comment: The work sheet remains the same throughout. Just one worksheet, but the ranges selected will have different values when saved as different workbooks. I hope that is clear.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex , I moved my worksheet to just before the first for loop and it works. How do I mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: You can answer your own post, with how you solved it. That's what I'd do :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Following @Alex's advice, I moved the Workbook and worksheet
to just before the first for ... loop.

```py
while i < 5:
    wb = xl.load_workbook(file.xlsx)
    ws = wb[0]
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=18, min_col=2, max_col=91, max_row=41):
        for cell in row:
```

This solved my problem.